# Is it possible to create a Django model's managed attributes (@property) with the parameter

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a function that depends on an external parameter

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_filed = ...

    @property
    def my_property(self, user=None):
        try:
            qs = OtherModel.objects.get(field1=self, user=user)
        except OtherModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return qs.field2
```

So I need annotate with my_property like this

```
MyModel.objects.all().annotate(field2=my_property(user=user))
```

Comment: This makes no sense. You can't define a property that takes a method; why don't you use a normal method? And why do you think you need to - or can - use annotate?

Comment: I need for ordering by filed (field2) like: MyModel.objects.all().annotate(field2=my_property(user=user)).order_by('field2')

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this completely the wrong way. As I said, you can't define a property that takes a parameter; the whole point of defining a method is that you reference it directly without the calling parentheses, so there is literally no way to pass it a parameter. And using annotate makes no sense here either; that defines a database operation, so it can't possibly refer to a method defined in Python.

Luckily your actual desired result is very simple, and does not require either a property or annotate. You just need to use the standard query syntax:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(othermodel__user=user).order_by(othermodel__field2)
```